# How can I query on the result I get from another query in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a collection name products which contains the document like:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5acbc75adcc6772eecfca8a2"), 
"name" : "HP 15q-by002ax (2TZ85PA) Notebook (APU Dual Core A9/ 4GB/ 1TB/ 
 WIn10/ 2GB Graph)", 
"price" : "24990", 
"brand" : "HP", 
"tags" : [
    "hp", 
    "15q", 
    "by002ax", 
    "2tz85pa", 
    "notebook", 
    "apu", 
    "dual", 
    "core", 
    "a9", 
    "4g"
],  "specifications" : {
    "full_specs" : {
        "General" : {
            "Model" : "2TZ85PA#ACJ", 
            "Utility" : "Everyday Use", 
            "OS" : "Windows 10 Home (64-bit)", 
            "Dimensions" : "253.7 x 380 x 23.88 mm", 
            "Weight" : "2.1 Kg", 
            "Warranty" : "1 Year Onsite Warranty"
        }, 
        "Display" : {
            "Type" : "HD LED Backlit Widescreen BrightView Display", 
            "Touch" : "No", 
            "Size" : "15.6 inches", 
            "Resolution" : "1366 x 768 pixels", 
            "PPI" : "~ 100", 
            "Aspect Ratio" : "16"
        }, 
        "Connectivity" : {
            "Ethernet" : "Integrated 10/100/1000 Gigabit LAN", 
             "WiFi" : "IEEE 802.11b/g/n", 
            "Bluetooth" : "v4.0", 
            "Lan Port" : "Yes", 
            "USB Ports" : "1 x USB 2.0, 2 x USB 3.0", 
            "HDMI" : "1 x HDMI Port (v1.4b)", 
            "Card Reader" : "3-in-1 Card Reader (SD, SDHC, SDXC)", 
            "Microphone In" : "Yes", 
            "Security Lock Port" : "Kensington Lock Slot"
        }, 
        "Input" : {
            "Camera" : "HP TrueVision HD Webcam", 
            "Keyboard" : "Full Size Textured Island-style Keyboard with 
 Numeric Keypad", 
            "Pointer Device" : "Multi Gesture Touchpad", 
            "Inbuilt Microphone" : "Single Digital Microphone", 
            "Speakers" : "Built-in, Stereo Speakers", 
            "Optical Drive" : "Yes", 
            "Optical Drive Speed" : "8x"
        }, 
        "Processor" : {
            "Processor" : "AMD APU Dual Core A9 A9-9420", 
            "Speed" : "3 GHz, Dual Core (Turbo Boost Upto 3.52 GHz)", 
            "Cache" : "1 MB", 
            "Brand" : "AMD", 
            "Series" : "APU Dual Core", 
            "Model" : "A9-9420"
        }, 
        "Graphics" : {
            "GPU" : "AMD Radeon 520 Graphics", 
            "Dedicated Memory" : "2 GB DDR3", 
            "Brand" : "AMD"
        }, 
        "Memory" : {
            "RAM" : "4 GB DDR4", 
            "RAM Bus Speed" : "1866 MHz", 
            "Maximum RAM Supported" : "Upto 16 GB", 
            "RAM Slots" : "2", 
            "Hard Disk Capacity" : "1 TB", 
            "Hard Disk Speed" : "5400 RPM"
        }, 
        "Battery" : {
            "Battery" : "4 Cell Battery"
        }, 
        "Extra" : {
            "Sales Package" : "Laptop, Battery, Power Adaptor, User Guide, 
Warranty Documents"
        }
    }
}},

{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5acbc75adcc6772eecfca8a3"), 
"name" : "Dell 3565 Notebook (7th Gen APU Dual Core A9/ 6GB/ 1TB/ Win10 Home)", 
"price" : "28990", 
"brand" : "Dell", 
"tags" : [
    "dell", 
    "3565", 
    "notebook", 
    "7th", 
    "gen", 
    "apu", 
    "dual", 
    "core", 
    "a9", 
    "6gb", 
    "1tb"
],   "specifications" : {
    "full_specs" : {
        "General" : {
            "Series" : "Inspiron", 
            "Model" : "A561226SIN9", 
            "Utility" : "Everyday Use", 
            "OS" : "Windows 10 Home (64-bit)", 
            "Warranty" : "1 Year Onsite Warranty"
        }, 
        "Display" : {
            "Type" : "HD LED Backlit Truelife Display", 
            "Touch" : "No", 
            "Size" : "15.6 inches", 
            "Resolution" : "1366 x 768 pixels", 
            "PPI" : "~ 100", 
            "Aspect Ratio" : "16"
        }, 
        "Connectivity" : {
            "Ethernet" : "10/100/1000 Mbps", 
            "WiFi" : "IEEE 802.11ac", 
            "Bluetooth" : "v4.1", 
            "Lan Port" : "Yes", 
            "USB Ports" : "1 x USB 2.0, 2 x USB 3.0", 
            "HDMI" : "1 x HDMI Port (v1.4a)", 
            "Card Reader" : "3-in-1 Card Reader (SD, SDHC, SDXC)", 
            "Microphone In" : "Yes"
        }, 
        "Input" : {
            "Camera" : "Integrated HD Webcam", 
            "Keyboard" : "English Non-Backlit Keyboard", 
            "Keyboard Backlit" : "Yes", 
            "Pointer Device" : "Touchpad", 
            "Inbuilt Microphone" : "Single Digital Microphone", 
            "Speakers" : ", Stereo Speakers", 
            "Sound" : "2 x Tuned Speakers with Waves MaxxAudio Pro", 
            "Optical Drive" : "Yes", 
            "Optical Drive Speed" : "8x"
        }, 
        "Processor" : {
            "Processor" : "AMD APU Dual Core A9 7th Gen A9-9400", 
            "Speed" : "2.4 GHz, Dual Core", 
            "Cache" : "1 MB", 
            "Brand" : "AMD", 
            "Series" : "APU Dual Core", 
            "Model" : "A9-9400"
        }, 
        "Graphics" : {
            "GPU" : "Integrated AMD Graphics", 
            "Brand" : "AMD"
        }, 
        "Memory" : {
            "RAM" : "6 GB DDR4", 
            "RAM Bus Speed" : "2400 MHz", 
            "Maximum RAM Supported" : "Upto 8 GB", 
            "RAM Slots" : "2", 
            "Hard Disk Capacity" : "1 TB", 
            "Hard Disk Speed" : "5400 RPM"
        }, 
        "Battery" : {
            "Battery" : "4 Cell Battery", 
            "Battery Backup" : "Upto 5 Hours"
        }, 
        "Extra" : {
            "Sales Package" : "Laptop, Battery, Power Adaptor, User Guide, Warranty Documents"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Now I query on this collection like:

```
  product.find({$and:[{"specifications.full_specs.Processor.Brand": {$in: cpu}}, {brand:{$in: brand}}]}).exec(function(error, result){
  if(error){
    console.log("here is an error in filtering");
  }
  else {
    console.log(result);
    var l1 = result.length;
        console.log("Result after filtering is ");
        console.log(result);
        console.log(cpu);
                console.log(l1);
        console.log("I am here with filtering 2");
        console.log("API SUCCESSOR");
        res.json({STATUS:"SUCCESSOR"});
  }
});
```

Here cpu and brand is the name of the array.

Now I want to query on the result I get from the above query.

Can I query on that result like:

```
db.products.find({price:{$gt:"2900",$lt:"500000"}}).pretty().length();
```

or any other query that I want on the result.

and then return the final result in my application.

Comment: yes, just nest the call inside the  callback, for example, put it where you declare `l1`. You can use async.js to avoid callback hell. Or switch to promises and async await which are supported natively in node 8+

Comment: Just add the query conditions to the original query i.e `db.products.find({ "specifications.full_specs.Processor.Brand": { "$in": cpu }, brand: { "$in": brand }, price: { "$gt": 2900, "$lt": 500000 } })`. Or is your actual problem that you don't know how to "merge" two objects in order to add conditions to a base query? At any rate, note that `"price"` presently does not have "numeric" values in your data. As such `"295"` is actually **greater than** `"2900"` in lexical order. So would be `"3"` for that matter. So you really **need** to fix that in your data.

Comment: @Catalyst No you cannot do that. A "query" is a "query" and you cannot actually issue another set of query conditions on those query results on the database. There are "views" available in modern MongoDB releases, but that is not actually what the OP appears to be asking, and there is a **much simpler** approach, as already mentioned.

Comment: @NeilLunn I was referring to resolving the request, and using the data to build a subsequent one.  You can always do that.

Comment: My problem is that here I use two array and $and query, if one array do not contain any value then it will give no result as output.
That is why I am asking that I use the query on result I get from another query.
I can check the length of the array and if the length of the array is greater then 0 then I apply the query otherwise I use only the previous query.